# Plotting a Function of a Complex Variable

Tags: complex-analysis, graphing-functions

I've been teaching myself complex analysis using "Introductory Complex Analysis" by Richard A. Silverman, and I'm a few chapters in and still have no clue how to plot anything. I know that

$$ z = x + iy $$

corresponds to an imaginary plane and a real plane, ie

$$ z = x^{2} + iy $$

Gives a parabolic plane for the real part, and a flat plane for the imaginary part.
The issue I'm having is plotting

$$ w = f(z) = u+vi $$

where

$$ u\rightarrow u(x,y) \wedge v\rightarrow v(x,y) .$$

I get the idea that 1 function of a complex variable produces two graphs that can be regarded as real, so would I be correct in assuming that:

$$ f(z) = w = z^{2} = (x +iy)(x +iy) = x^2 + i2xy -y^{2} $$

thus

$$ u=x^{2} - y^{2} \wedge v=2xy  $$

as applied to the definition above, giving me the real plot "u" and an imaginary plot "v", are the only two graphs? Also, which -- if either -- is to be regarded as the w plane and the z plane?

Comment: [This](http://www.pacifict.com/ComplexFunctions.html) might be helpful.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! As an editorial suggestion, if you put your equations between double dollar signs, they center nicely.

Comment: See [Domain coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_coloring).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly, the collection of points $x+iy$ gives you a single plane. It has in it the real axis and the imaginary axis, but it's just one plane.

The graph of a function $f:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ is a four dimensional object (since $\mathbb C$ is a two-dimensional object). So, if you are having trouble visualizing the graph it ok - it's just because most people are not very good at visualizing in four dimensions.

As you say, every function $f:\mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ gives rise to two real valued functions $u,v:\mathbb C \to \mathbb R$. The graph of each of these is a three dimensional object that can be plotted. The two graphs together determine the given function $f$ but the the visual information given by the geometry of these component real-valued functions' graphs is quite limited if you want for the study of $f$ as an analytic function. I hope this helps clearing some of the confusion.

Comment: For the most part. This particular text references w and z planes. From what I've stated above, what variables make up which plane?

Comment: The $z$ plane is usually referring to the domain of $f$ and the $w$ plane to the codomain.

Comment: Ah. So the z plane plane has axes (x,iy), where the w plane has axes (f(z),z) then?

Comment: not quite. The $w$ plane has coordinates (t,s). The graph of the function is the set $\{((x,iy),f(x,iy))\}$, which consists of four coordinates in total since $f(x,iy)$ is in the $w$ plane.

Comment: (t,s)? Are those just arbitrary?

Comment: yes, as arbitrary as the $x,y$ in $(x,iy)$, these are just variable names.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of complex functions as  maps from one plane (say, $z$) to another ($w$). Both of these planes have a real axis (usually shown horizontal) and an imaginary axis (usually vertical). Maps from 2D space to 2D space are hard to picture but it can be done in [a number of ways](https://www.pacifict.com/ComplexFunctions.html). One of the most helpful (for me) is using color to represent the output of the function (called [domain coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_coloring)). You can try it [here](https://people.math.osu.edu/fowler.291/phase/), and if you want more functionality (like showing the magnitude as contours) I put together some Python code [here](https://github.com/seaplant3/complex-plotting).

Answer (score 1):

There are (at least) two approaches to this problem:

- [domain coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_coloring)
- plotting contour lines at equal absolute value and/or equal phase

With [cplot](https://github.com/nschloe/cplot) (a Python package that I wrote) you can use both of these; for example for
$$
f(z) = \frac{\sin(z^3)}{z}
$$

```
import cplot
import numpy as np


def f(z):
    return np.sin(z ** 3) / z


cplot.show(f, (-2.0, +2.0), (-2.0, +2.0), 1000)
```

[image]